# Restart Service If TCP Check Fails or Timeout

Tags: linux, monitoring, check-mk

We are using check_mk WATO to monitor our production infrastructure and all the services. Currently, we have HTTP checks for our application. We would like to have an event driven monitoring system where if an event is triggered, nagios/check_mk should perform certain action, like restart tomcat if HTTP check times out.

Is there any option available in WATO?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/eventhandlers.html

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking to implement it via check_mk. Anyways found the solution. [link](http://lists.mathias-kettner.de/pipermail/checkmk-en/2012-May/005730.html)